# Suggest that a Wikipedia page be renamed

Tags: wikipedia

I've found a couple of pages and categories on Wikipedia with confusing names. Is there any template that I can use to suggest that these pages be renamed, without actually renaming them myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the way to go about doing something like that is to start a discussion on the attached talk page. Explain why you find the page name confusing and, perhaps, what your suggested change is.

Don't forget to sign with `~~~~`.

Comment: Is there any way that I can add the renaming suggestions to a "list of pages to be renamed" (so that the suggestions won't go unnoticed for too long?) There is currently no way to directly "move" categories from one page to another, and this a bug that has existed for a long time.

Comment: Alternately, if I simply replace the text of a category with a redrirect page, will all of the category's pages be automatically moved by a bot?

Comment: That's exactly what [Categories for discussion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Categories_for_discussion) is for.